# Cronjob setup for laravel 4.2 in cpanel

Tags: laravel, cron, cpanel

I am using `laravel 4.2`. I have created command file for cron job and added it into artisan file. I tested it in command. Everything is working fine in localhost. In Cpanel server I gave command path like,

```
php /home/fridayburr/public_html/version1/artisan active:user 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But cron job is not working.

Comment: try running that command in ssh terminal and see if that works.

Comment: Did you mention the cron name in kernel.php ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did in my shared Hosting using CPANEL

[image: Cronjob Configuration for Laravel with Shared Hosting]

Here CRON Task is set on UNIX, to run every minute.

Add the schedule call with appropriate time schedule.

[laravel Schedule documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling)

[image: Kernel File to execute the Crons in laravel]